# Top and bottom margin with longtable

Tags: margins, longtable

Is it possible to define a top and bottom margin for all `longtable` in the entire document? My current solution works, but it forces me to repeat code every time I use `longtable`. I would like to add a distance for the top and the bottom of `3em`.

```
\vspace{3em}
\begin{longtable}{…}
    …
\end{longtable}
\vspace{3em}
```

Comment: `\setlenth\LTpre{3em}` `\setlength\LTpost{3em}` but note these are not top and bottom margin they won't affect spaces at a page break.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle you're missing a `g` there. Should be `\setlength\LTpre{3em}`.

Comment: @Skillmon oops, yes;-)

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Thanks David! Precisely what I was looking for.

Comment: What is the answer for the margins at the top and bottom of a page?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`\setlength\LTpre{3em} \setlength\LTpost{3em}` will set the length before and after the long table. (This isn't really a mrgin setting, it is space added in the page body, before and after the table, not above and below each page of a multi-page table.)